# How to look ahead to next event in Midi Sequence

Tags: java, midi, javax.sound.midi

We are trying to code a simple guitar hero clone for university using javax.sound.midi.

Currently we can play back a midi file with a sequencer and log the midi event that is currently played. However, we want to display the *upcoming* event (more specifically, the  the data bytes in the MIDI message that indicate the note).

We are currently using a Sequencer to play the sounds and a Receiver and that logs the sound to the console. However, it logs it the exact moment the sound is played, not the upcoming sound.

In Sequencer class:

```
public void startSequencer() {
    try {
        sequencer.open();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(BPM);
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(song));
        sequencer.setSequence(is);
        sequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(receiver);

        sequencer.start();

        while (sequencer.isRunning()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        sequencer.close();

        System.out.println(receiver.getNoteOnAmount());

    } catch (MidiUnavailableException | InterruptedException | IOException | InvalidMidiDataException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

---

In Receiver class:

```
public void send(MidiMessage message, long timeStamp) {
    //If the Status is NOTE_ON (144), process the note
    if (message.getStatus() == 144) {
        System,out.println(message.getMessage()[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the `Sequence` from the `Sequencer` using `Sequencer.getSequence()`.

All the `MidiEvents` from the Midi file are stored  in one or more `Track` instances within the `Sequence`. A `MidiEvent` is a `MidiMessage` with a tick position. `MidiEvents` are ordered by tick position.

So in your `Receiver.send(MidiMessage)` method, search the tracks to find the `MidiEvent` which corresponds to the received `MidiMessage`.

If you have only one track and find the corresponding `MidiEvent` at index `meIndex`/tick `meTick`, then the next `MidiEvents` to be played are at `meIndex+1`, `meIndex+2` etc.  If you have several tracks, you also need to search other tracks for `MidiEvents` whose tick position is right after `meTick`.

Of course there is plenty of room for optimization (e.g. preprocess `Tracks` in advance), so that you don't spend time reparsing all the Tracks each time you receive a note.